# "extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11", I'm Getting this error

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector <int> num = {2,3,4};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It tells you that extended initializer lists are only available with c++11 (or later). You need to tell your compiler to use C++11 (or later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below style of initialization is only introduced in C++ 11.

```
vector <int> num = {2,3,4};
```

This is not available in initial C++ version. That is what your gcc compiler is complaining. You need to tell the compiler to use C++11 version. Use below command.

```
g++ -std=c++11 myProgram.cpp
```

Comment: Note: You can also compile to C++ Standards that come after C++11.